# How to filter array of objecs with an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to filter an array of objects by items of another array. This is my list of items:

```
const list = ["first", "second", "third"]
```

This array can be empty, with one, two or three itens... By example:

```
const list = []
const list = ["first"]
let list = ["first", "third"]
```

So, I need to use my `list` to filter my `myArr2` by status.

```
const myArr2 = [
  {
    id: "1",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "first"    
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "first"    
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "second"    
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "third"    
  },      
  {
    id: "5",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "second"    
  },      
]
```

If my `list` is:

```
const list = [ "first", "third" ]
```

The output must be:

```
const myArr2 = [
  {
    id: "1",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "first"    
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "first"    
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "third"    
  },      
]
```

If my `list` is:

```
const list = [ "first" ]
```

The output must be:

```
const myArr2 = [
  {
    id: "1"
    language: "portuguese"
    status: "first"    
  },
  {
    id: "2"
    language: "portuguese"
    status: "first"    
  }  
}
```

and so on...

I made this code but not works properly:

```
Object.entries(list).forEach(status => {
  myArr2.filter(item => {
    if(item.status === status){
      return item
    }
  })
})
```

What am I doing wrong?
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it in what I will say reverse manner. You need to check for each item in myArr2 that whether the item has its status which is present in the list array. You can do it as follows -

### Correct Code -

```js
let myArr2 = [
  {
    id: "1",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "first"    
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "first"    
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "second"    
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "third"    
  },      
  {
    id: "5",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "second"    
  },      
];
const list = [ "first", "third" ]

myArr2 = myArr2.filter(item => list.includes(item.status))
console.log(myArr2)
```

---

### Mistake in your approach

> ```
> Object.entries(list).forEach(status => {
>   myArr2.filter(item => {
>     if(item.status === status){
>       return item
>     }
>   })
> })
> ```

In the above approach, you will be iterating through the first element in the list (that is `first` ). So, it will filter out all the items from `myArr2` which are not having status as first.

In the next iteration, you will check with second element in the list(that is `second`). So, now it will further again filter out all the items from `myArr2` which do not have status as `second`. Since no elements have their status as both first and second at the same time, your code would probably return the resultant array as an empty array .

---

**NOTE**: you would need to assign the new array returned by `myArr2` to some variable. The `filter` method doesn't filter out elements in-place. So, since you have not done that, your code would probably be giving you the origin array itself if you try checking it by console logging.

You can read more about `filter()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) .

Comment: Thank u so much for you great explanation! It's cleanner for me, thanks

Comment: @Zkk Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could destructure `status` and check if `list` contains this value.

```
result = myArr2.filter(({ status }) => list.includes(status));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the array. Check for this if the elements are part of your filterlist (indexOf != -1).

```js
function filterArray(arr, list) {
    return arr.filter(el => {
        return list.indexOf(el.status)!=-1;
    });
}

const myArr2 = [
  {
    id: "1",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "first"    
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "first"    
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "second"    
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "third"    
  },      
  {
    id: "5",
    language: "portuguese",
    status: "second"    
  },      
]

list1 = []
list2 = ["first"]
list3 = ["first", "third"]

console.log(filterArray(myArr2, list3));
console.log(filterArray(myArr2, list2));
console.log(filterArray(myArr2, list1));
```